# Data in Tableau is multiplied by a factor of 18 when compared with Tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api

When Data is viewed in Tableau, the measure value is multiplied by a factor of 18.

for example, excel data shows # PO's checked for Week 30 is 21. when pulled this information in tableau, it is showing as 378(21*18) for Week 30. All the rest of the weeks are inflated by a factor of 18.

Comment: Are you using the correct measure? (e.g. `count` or `average` instead of `sum` or something like that). And is the Level of Detail correct?

Comment: To help us help you troubleshoot, please share a workbook, dataset or the objective you are after. Tableau doesn't multiply by 18 without a reason. One explanation is that you might be running your calculation at the row level when what's needed is to calculate against the aggregate.

Comment: @NielsHenkens : I should be using SUM only. The data present in Excel is summarized at week level in a row and when we are taking this into Tableau, it is multiplied by a factor 18.

Comment: Does your datasource contain multiple rows with the same data or rows containing totals as well as weekly summaries? Tableau will add up all the rows in the dataset which for badly structured datasets will contain the raw data plus totals.

Answer (score 0):

@robcrock: i cannot post the file or screenshots due to technical issues. When i tried to re-create the viz. in a new tableau sheet, it is working fine. But this Viz. needs to be appended to final Output, where other viz. are made. In Final output, we are having this multiplying factor of 18.

Note: Final output file contains pivot fields used in another worksheets. does using pivots in tableau might be the reason?

Comment: This shouldn't cause such a problem. But it is very hard to say/diagnose without knowing what your data looks like and how you made the viz.